# Pandoc URL anchor character encoding

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

I have a markdown document I converted to PDF using the command

```
pandoc --pdf-engine tectonic --from markdown --template eisvogel --listings -V linkcolor:blue --output test.pdf test.md
```

The conversion works well, but links with anchors in them are converted so the '#' is '%23'.  How can I get round this?

```
[this link](https://example.com/pages/mypage#heading)
```

becomes

```
[this link](https://example.com/pages/mypage%23heading)
```

which gives a 404.

Answer (score 0):

could you not just use a typical output format. Seems like you might be needing a specific format for a specific reason though.

```
\---
title: "Habits"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
output: pdf_document
\---
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that the `output: pdf_document` element of the front matter will c ause pandoc to process URIs properly?

Comment: Yes. I haven't had issues with my example. But I am not familiar with your code arguments, just a suggestion. Let me know how it works for you. I'd like to learn more

Comment: Hello thanks for the suggestion but this does not work with the tectonic latex engine at least.  I'm wondering if a different engine might perform better in this respect.  I'll see what I can do and report back.

Comment: The only other link I found for markdown links was the one below. Apologize I couldn't be more help. `pandoc --from markdown --to markdown --wrap=preserve --reference-links \ 
 --output outputfile.md inputfile.md`

Comment: Interestingly, running md-md ruins the layout I see but produces a perfectly good PDF, except the anchored links are still not fixed.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I think I'm gonna have to wrestle with a HTML intermediary.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem. I've settled on the following workaround with **xelatex** pdf-engine:

```
<a href="https://example.com/pages/mypage#heading">this link</a>
```

Not sure the regular `[this link](https://example.com/pages/mypage#heading)` is a bug or I just need to dig deeper into the documentation. But for now, I'm good :)